# generalized cylinder

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the surface defined as $S = \{ \gamma(u) + va : (u, v) \in I \times \mathbb{R}\}$
> where $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth, non-self-intersecting curve and $a$ is a unit vector such that $\dot{\gamma}$ is never parallel to $a$. Prove that S is a smooth surface.

A surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth surface if each coordinate chart in the atlas of $S$ is regular. A surface patch $\sigma : U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is called regular if $\sigma$ is smooth and
$\partial_{x_1}\sigma$ is linearly independent to $\partial_{x_2}\sigma$ for each $x = (x_1, x_2) \in U$. I considered the natural map $\sigma(u,v) = \gamma(u) + va$ for $(u, v) \in I \times \mathbb{R}$, which is clealy smooth. If $S$ forms a surface with the charts $\sigma$ then it is clear that $S$ is smooth, since $\sigma_{u} = \dot{\gamma}$ and $\sigma_{v} = a$ are linearly independent because they are not parallel (cross product is non zero).

However, I am unable to show that $\sigma$ is a homeomorphism. $\sigma$ is onto and continuous. The problematic part is one-one and showing that the inverse is continuous. $\sigma$ is one-one if $\sigma(u',v') = \sigma(u,v) \implies \gamma(u')-\gamma(u)=(v-v')a$ implies that $u=u'$ and $v=v'$. How can i precisely show that $\sigma$ is a homeomorphism ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Why is the map one-to-one? The given hypotheses do not guarantee that. Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: I couldn't find a counter example. If this is not one-one then I will have to look for a different mapping. How I solve this ?

Comment: Try a circular helix on a circular cylinder. Does that suggest a fix?

Comment: @TedShifrin I took $\gamma(t) = (\cos{t},\sin{t},t)$, then $\dot{\gamma(t)} = (-\sin{t},\cos{t},1)$. For $a = (0,0,1)$, the map $\sigma$ is not one-one. But this doesn't prove anything, I need to look for new charts now.

Comment: So what is the *right* way to parametrize a right circular cylinder? How do you arrive at that from the helix?

Comment: I don't know :/

Comment: Certainly you know a standard way to parametrize the right circular cylinder.